# Building on top of a wordpress.org site?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I know html and css only.  Should I build on top of a wordpress site so I can reuse the current CMS, or should I build the site from scratch and add CMS plugins later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what functionality you need and what time you've got available. I agree with Brendan in that you will learn more building it yourself from scratch. The same could be said for anything though - think how much you'd know about building and mechanical engineering after building your own house and car from scratch.

Using open source tools and platforms will allow you to get a working site up and running much much quicker. If you take the time to learn the system rather than just grab a theme and smash in a load of plugins in then it will stand you in good stead for eventually building your own stuff. Just my 2c.

Answer (score -1):

If you know only html and css, work on top of wordpress. You can have account on Wordpress.org, but they do not allow major changes in the site.

A step by step guide will be:

1. install wordpress package on your server.
2. look for free themes and
3. install on your server modify the theme using the editor, reinstall
   the theme if something goes wrong.
4. install plugins to enhance site
   experience.

I got my site working like that, keep experimenting, wordpress is fun. :)